# datamember property 'System' cannot be found on the DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms

I am binding a `Dictionary` to a `ComboBox`. This seems to work alright without any compile errors, but at runtime I get the error:

> datamember property 'System' cannot be found on the DataSource

Here is my code:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> valuList
{
  set
  {
    lComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(value,null);
    lComboBox.DisplayMember = (value.Keys).ToString();
    lComboBox.ValueMember = (value.Values).ToString();
  }
}

Dictionary<string, string> x6 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
x6.Add("AS", "ASS");
x6.Add("AAS", "AASS");
myForm.valuList = x6;
```

Comment: is your value key or values called "System"? is it missing? **Edit** you should post what value can contain

Comment: When do you get the error ? Do you get it when you select a item or when the application fires up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the display member to be the *key* of each pair in the dictionary, and the value member to be the *value* of each pair, you probably want:

```
lComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
lComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

You should be aware that the order will be undetermined though - is that really what you want?

Calling `ToString()` on the return value of `Dictionary<,>.Keys` or `Dictionary<,>.Values` is probably just going to give you the fully-qualified name of a type, which will start with `System.Collections...` - that's why you're getting the current error.

I'd also strongly encourage you to rename your property to something which follows the .NET naming conventions, and also *means* something.

Comment: I did what you said and used "Value.value" as displaymemeber as I want the data, but I always just get 1 even though value is containing 3 memebers. I looked in value and the hirarchy was value.Value.THINGS as I used a custom object not string for value, why is it always 1 of the values?

Comment: However, "Key" gives me the 3 keys

Comment: @justanidiot: Sorry, I have no idea how to understand your comments. You clearly have a *lot* more context than you've included in your question - where the dictionary is just of strings...

Comment: but should I assume its a matter of digging into my object somehow ? Value. . . ?

Comment: @justanidiot: No, you've passed in a dictionary - which is a collection of `KeyValuePair` entries. So for each of those entries, it's going to extract the `Key` property (the key in the entry) to display, and the `Value` property (the value in the entry) as the value. It's not really clear what you're trying to do...

Comment: @justanidiot: Sorry, it's still not at all clear what you mean... or how you expect the combobox to handle `Option<double>`.

Comment: I wonder if you recommend a better gui than the combobox for Dictionaries like that ?

Comment: @justanidiot: No, because I still don't really understand what you're trying to do. I suggest you ask a separate question with a *lot* more detail - we're getting off the topic of the original question.